# my bootstrap 4 Cards are not shrinking to fit in mobile screen

Tags: html, css

what I want is in large device screen there should be one card in a row and same for mobile devices that are in small screen.
my bootstrap nav bar is working perfectly on the mobile device and large screen but with my cards, there is one issue, it's not shrinking to fit in small screen devices.[image: here is the picture of the issue] I have to scroll to view the whole card. 
here is my code for cards

```
<% include partials/header %>
  <div class="row text-center" id="post-center">
        <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
              <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-title float-left"><%= post.username %></p>
                </div>
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="<%= post.image %>" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">                        
                      <p class="card-text"><%=post.description%></p>
                  </div>
              </div>  
              <br>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

and here is my header file code where I have my nav bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>9tech</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet/custom.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome cdn-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar static-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color:white;">9tech</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded  ="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link " href="/posts" style="color:white;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white;">About</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/signup" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"> Sign Up </i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/login"> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Log In </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
          </div>

        </nav>
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong

and here is my custom css file

```
ul li a {
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
}



html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #E7ECF2;

}

#post-center{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add width: 100% to the image.

Comment: not working, I add that in custom CSS file still no change.

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the width:25 rem; property from div with the card as a class, then the cards become responsive to mobile devices. but it becomes a gigantic image in the large screen devices.

Comment: To me it looked little incomplete but based on understanding I suggest to add  "container" class for first element which holds the entire layout. It gives fixed layout. Also provide width:100% to img. Hope this helps.